# Notice: Undefined index: PK_CMS_PAGE in \vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadata.php on line 96

Tags: cms, magento2.2.6, cms-pages

I shifted my site from server to local. But it shows an error like this:

> Notice: Undefined index: **PK_CMS_PAGE** in
>   \vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadata.php on line 96

can anyone please suggest me how to fix this.

Note: I have already browsed about the issue, and found the solution as the primary key of **CMS_PAGE** may be missed. But my **CMS_PAGE** table has a primary key.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There must be issue with Primary key in table. kindly update table and then run below command :

```
 rm -rf generated/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/* && rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* && php bin/magento c:f && php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Comment: is this sql command or ssh?

Comment: you need to execute this in SSH or CLI

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:
rm -rf generated/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/* && rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* && php bin/magento c:f && php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f

thanks charvi Parikh